# What fonts does iOS have, and does it support @font-face?

Tags: iphone, css, ios, fonts, font-face

I googled this topic hard and found only references from 2007... I guess things have changed since then.
I'm looking for a definitive list or guide of all the font support on the latest safari mobile for iPhone and iPad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't have searched that hard ...

[iosfonts.com](http://iosfonts.com/)

is the top result returned by Google and lists all fonts available on iPhone and iPad (*as there are differences*) from iOS 4.3 which is the latest publicly available version.

Comment: This was actually my top result turned by Google...

Answer (score 1):

http://www.iphone-ipad-fonts.com/ ... includes screenshots

and @font-face is available on the iOS only through the web view (UIWebView)

Answer (score 0):

I think it supports anything HTML5 and css3 supports. I stand corrected.

See http://www.jquery4u.com/mobile/50-jquery-mobile-development/